# How to implement a virtual D-Pad on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, opengl-es

I'm having trouble implementing a virtual D-pad in an EAGLView (OpenGL ES). I thought this would be simple but it is not. It is not so straightforward to determine whether a touch is on a certain portion of the D-Pad at any given time. Does anyone know of some good (relevant, please) resources online or could maybe post some source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the iPhone Quake 3 port.
The relevant file is [here](http://code.google.com/p/quake3-iphone/source/browse/trunk/code/iphone/Q3ScreenView.m).
One of the authors has a [blog post describing that technique](http://diaryofagraphicsprogrammer.blogspot.com/2008/12/ip-programming-tip-8.html).